# Why there is difference in the scope of the variable in same type of functions in angularjs controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I added a functionality where I can add and remove the data and pushing them as object. However One is taking the value out of the function scope while another is not, I am not getting why or I am missing something?
I am able to collect `$scope.projectDetails.allocateResourceInfo`
In short how to show `$scope.projectDetails.allocatePeopleInfo` in `AddProjectDetails function` ?

**Possible reason I think** : due to auto search, Item is getting empty, but I don't know, if I have already pushed that data in the array before I do next search, how it is lost in first place in people functionality but remains in the resource functionality.

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('addProjectCtrl', ['$http', '$scope', '$state', addProjectCtrl]);

function addProjectCtrl($http, $scope, $state, backendUrl, $auth) {
    var self = this;

    $scope.projectDetails = {};
    self.searchTextChange = searchTextChange;
    self.searchAllocatedResource = searchAllocatedResource;
    /* searchTextChange collects the text on the autofilter bar and gets the result from remote server everytime the text is changed */
    function searchTextChange(text) {
```

// every text change in autosuggest gives the result set accordingly
            }, function(error) {
                console.log("error");
            });
        }

```
    $scope.searchItemData = function(item) {
     // this code on select of a particular drop down gives the complete json object for that selected item. coz the item scope ends in md-autosearch, i just copied it to seatchItem so that I can bass the json data set for any use outside the md-auto-controller and use it furtehr

        $scope.searchItem = item;
        return item.name + " as " + item.designation + " 100%";
    };

    pushing the required search result I want in this new array in projectDetails, so that I can pass all at once

    $scope.projectDetails.allocatePeopleInfo = [];
    $scope.addAllocatePeople = function(item) {
        $scope.projectDetails.allocatePeopleInfo.push({
            imgpath: item.imageUrl,
            name: item.name,
            designation: item.designation,
            email: item.email,
            percentage: '80.5%'
        });
        self.searchText = "";
        console.log($scope.projectDetails.allocatePeopleInfo); // data shows up
    }
    $scope.removeAllocatePeople = function(rAR) {
        var index = $scope.projectDetails.allocatePeopleInfo.indexOf(rAR);
        $scope.projectDetails.allocatePeopleInfo.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $scope.projectDetails.allocateResourceInfo = [];
    $scope.addAllocateResource = function(item1, item2) {
        $scope.projectDetails.allocateResourceInfo.push({
            resourceTitle: item1,
            resourceLink: item2,
        });
        $scope.resourceName = "";
        $scope.resourceLink = "";
    }
    $scope.removeAllocateResource = function(rAR) {
        var index = $scope.projectDetails.allocateResourceInfo.indexOf(rAR);
        $scope.projectDetails.allocateResourceInfo.splice(index, 1);
    }

    $scope.AddProjectDetails = function() {
        console.log($scope.projectDetails.allocatePeopleInfo); // no data is added in this variable
        console.log($scope.projectDetails.allocateResourceInfo); // its shows the data

    }
}
```

**autocomplete html**

```
<md-content layout-padding class=" padding-bottom-0" flex ng-controller="addProjectCtrl as ctrlAR">
            <md-input-contaner flex class="myclass" >
                <p class="overview_subheadings" style="margin-left:10px">Allocate People </p>

                <div layout="row">
                    <md-autocomplete
                            md-selected-item="ctrlAR.selectedItem"
                            md-search-text-change=""
                            md-search-text="ctrlAR.searchText"
                            md-selected-item-change="ctrlAR.selectedItemChange(item)"
                            md-items="item in ctrlAR.searchAllocatedResource(ctrlAR.searchText)"
                            md-item-text="searchItemData(item);"
                            md-min-length="0"
                            placeholder="Allocate People"
                            md-menu-class="autocomplete-custom-template" style="margin-top:7px; margin-left:10px"
                            ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 ? addAllocatePeople(searchItem) : null" flex>
                        <md-item-template>
                            <div class="item-title">
                                <md-list-item class="md-2-line" style="height: 50px;min-height: 50px;">
                                    <img pdb-alt-img ng-src="{{item.imageUrl}}" class="md-avatar"
                                         alt="{{item.name}}" profile="peerCover" style="margin-top: 4px"/>

                                    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column">
                                        <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>

                                        <p>{{item.designation}}</p>
                                    </div>
                                </md-list-item>
                            </div>
                      <span class="item-metadata">
                        <span class="item-metastat">
                        </span>
                      </span>
                        </md-item-template>

                    </md-autocomplete>

                    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More">
                        <md-icon md-font-library="material-icons"
                                 ng-click="addAllocatePeople(searchItem)" class="color-blue">add
                        </md-icon>
                    </md-button>
                </div>

            </md-input-contaner>

            <md-list style="margin-bottom:20px">
                <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="item in projectDetails.allocatePeopleInfo">
                    <img dir-alt-img ng-src="asdasd" class="md-avatar margin-23-top"
                         style="margin-top:5px"
                         dir-inverse="true" alt="{{item.name}}" profile="peerCover"/>

                    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column" flex="45">
                        <h4>{{item.name}}</h4>

                        <p>{{item.email}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column" flex="40">
                        <h3>{{item.designation}}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column" flex="10">
                        <h4><b>{{item.percentage}}</b></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="md-list-item-text" layout="column" flex="5">
                        <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More" flex>
                            <md-icon md-font-library="material-icons" class="close-font-color"
                                     style="margin-left:10px"
                                    ng-click="removeAllocatePeople(item)">close
                            </md-icon>
                        </md-button>
                    </div>
                    <md-divider></md-divider>
                </md-list-item>
            </md-list>
        </md-content>

**for resource data**


    <md-button class="md-icon-button" aria-label="More">
                                <md-icon md-font-library="material-icons"
                                         ng-click="addAllocateResource(val1,val2)" class="color-blue">add
                                </md-icon>
                            </md-button>
```

Resources i followed :angular material auto complete https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: How you are calling these functions? you cannot test $scope variables in controller initialization it will show you the initial values.

Comment: edited ... however its working fine with the resource but not with people

Comment: @Azzi that I was calling in some click event not outside ..

Comment: you may not initialized 'searchItem' (ng-click="addAllocatePeople(searchItem)")

Comment: how to fix this its angular material autocomplete

Comment: post your full code for debug or create a mock/test page as your page post it

Comment: Are u trying to say your topmost console shows the data for People and later in Add detail function, the same data is lost..?? If so, I suggest you should check if the 'item' variable passed at top is defined towards the end consoles.

Comment: You're putting too much code that people would not think of taking time to read, and your question does not state what you want to achieve or is unclear. Please revise.

Comment: updated a bit with comments